# How to publish smart contract to mainnet with Remix

Tags: ethereum, remix

I am comfortable using the Rinkeby test net for my smart contract, but soon I would like to deploy it to the mainnet.  Although I can only seem to find documentation for Polygon, but I would prefer to use the actual Ethereum mainnet.

Thanks!

Comment: There are few different ways to achieve the same result (deployment to mainnet). How do you currently deploy to the Rinkeby testnet? I'll try to formulate my answer based on your current approach.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  Right now, in remix I have the compiler set to 8.7, auto compile with optimization, and connected to "Injected Web 3", Rinkeby 4) Network is what it says under that.  Then I enter my constructer requirements (name, symbol, URI) and then  hit "transact".  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same in REMIX IDE, just switch the networks in metamask.
[image]

This one is for Matic = 137

This one is ETH Mainnet

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, and I notice it always defaults to 3000000 gas limit.  I've heard it's best not to change this, is that correct?  Even if you need to use more gas?

Comment: the explanation for gas is like  using it in your car. You need gas to get from point A to point B. if you run out of gas before reach point B, you can't continue( your transaction is rejected and you are returned at point A). You always need to set more or equal the gasLimit that will be used for the transaction. You can play with gasPrice , to pay less for the transaction, but wait more time. You pay only for the used gas.

Comment: if you set too low gasLimit, your transaction could run out of gas and get rejected, you will burn the used ETH and got a rejected transaction. Then you will need to pay the full price for another transaction with the correct gasLimit.